# CDK Pipelines - Migrating a database in the pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a `CDK Pipelines` pipeline that is handling the self mutation and deployment of my application on ECS and I am having a tough time figuring out how to implement database migrations.

My migration files as well as the migration command reside inside of the docker container that are built and deployed in the pipeline. Below are two things I've tried so far:

---

**My first thought** was just creating a `pre` step on the stage, but i believe there is a chicken/egg situation. Since the migration command requires database to exist (as well as having the endpoint and credentials) and the migration step is `pre`, the stack doesn't exist when this command would run...

```js
    const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "CdkCodePipeline", {
      // ...
      // ...
    }

    pipeline.addStage(applicationStage).addPre(new CodeBuildStep("MigrateDatabase", {
      input: pipeline.cloudAssemblyFileSet,
      buildEnvironment: {
        environmentVariables: {
          DB_HOST: { value: databaseProxyEndpoint },
          // ...
          // ...
        },
        privileged: true,
        buildImage: LinuxBuildImage.fromAsset(this, 'Image', {
          directory: path.join(__dirname, '../../docker/php'),
        }),
      },
      commands: [
        'cd /var/www/html',
        'php artisan migrate --force',
      ],
    }))
```

In the above code, `databaseProxyEndpoint` has been everything from a CfnOutput, SSM Parameter to a plain old typescript reference but all failed due to the value being empty, missing, or not generated yet.

I felt this was close, since it works perfectly fine until I try and reference `databaseProxyEndpoint`.

---

**My second attempt** was to create an init container in ECS.

```js
   const migrationContainer = webApplicationLoadBalancer.taskDefinition.addContainer('init', {
      image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromDockerImageAsset(webPhpDockerImageAsset),
      essential: false,
      logging: logger,
      environment: {
        DB_HOST: databaseProxy.endpoint,
        // ...
        // ...
      },
      secrets: {
        DB_PASSWORD: ecs.Secret.fromSecretsManager(databaseSecret, 'password')
      },
      command: [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        [
          "php artisan migrate --force",
        ].join(" && "),
      ]
    });

    // Make sure migrations run and our init container return success
    serviceContainer.addContainerDependencies({
      container: migrationContainer,
      condition: ecs.ContainerDependencyCondition.SUCCESS,
    });
```

This worked, but I am not a fan at all. The migration command should run once in the ci/cd pipeline on a deploy, not when the ECS service starts/restarts or scales... My migrations failed once and it locked up cloudformation because the health check failed both on the deploy and then naturally on the rollback as well causing a completely broken loop of pain.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to pull this off would save me from losing the remaining hair i have left!

Comment: Is the database also deployed with the same Pipeline?  Do you want the migrations to run each time the Pipeline executes?  Or to run only when the database resource is created?

Comment: @fedonev currently I have everything in one stack, but there is 100% flexibility here to adjust or split the stack up since the application hasn't launched yet. As far as when to run, in a perfect world i'd love for the migrate command to run once when the db is created, then once each time the pipeline runs. The command would run _before_ the ECS deploy so the migrations happen before the new code changes go live. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your migrations (1) within a stack's deployment with a Custom Resource construct, (2) after a stack's or stage's deployment with a `post` Step, (3) or after the pipeline has run with an EventBridge rule.

#### 1. Within a stack: Migrations as a Custom Resource

One option is to define your migrations as a [CustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources). It's a CloudFormation feature for executing user-defined code (typically in a Lambda) during the stack deployment lifecycle. See @mchlfchr's answer for an example. Also consider the CDK [Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.triggers-readme.html) construct, a higher-level Custom Resource implementation.

#### 2. After a stack or stage: "post" Step

If you split your application into, say, a `StatefulStack` (database) and `StatelessStack` (application containers), you can run your migrations code as a `post` [Step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#validation) between the two. This is the approach attempted in the OP.

In your `StatefulStack`, the variable producer, expose a `CfnOutput` instance variable for the environment variable values: `readonly databaseProxyEndpoint: CfnOutput`. Then consume the variables in a pipeline migration action by passing them to a `post` step as `envFromCfnOutputs`. The CDK will synth them into CodePipeline [Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html):

```js
pipeline.addStage(myStage, { // myStage includes the StatefulStack and StatelessStack instances
    stackSteps: [
        {
            stack: statefulStack,
            post: [
                new pipelines.CodeBuildStep("Migrate", {
                    commands: [ 'cd /var/www/html', 'php artisan migrate --force',],
                    envFromCfnOutputs: { TABLE_ARN: stack1.tableArn },
                    // ... other step config
                }),
            ],
        },
    ],
    post: // steps to run after the stage
});
```

The `addStage` method's [stackSteps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.AddStageOpts.html#stacksteps) option runs post steps after a specific stack in a stage.  The [post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.AddStageOpts.html) option work similarly, but runs after the stage.

#### 3. After the Pipeline execution: EventBridge rule

Although it's likely not the best option, you could run migrations after the pipeline executes. CodePipeline [emits events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/detect-state-changes-cloudwatch-events.html) during pipeline execution. With an EventBridge rule, listen for `CodePipeline Pipeline Execution State Change` events where `"state": "SUCCEEDED"`.

---

**Note on failure modes:** The three options have different failure modes. If the migrations fail as a Custom Resource, the `StatefulStack` deployment will fail (with changes rolled back) and the pipeline execution will fail. If the migrations are implemented as a step, the pipeline execution will fail but the `StatefulStack` won't roll back. Finally, if migrations are event-triggered, a failed migration will affect neither the stack nor execution, as they will already be finished when the migrations run.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I'm wondering now though if #2 is even possible? The migration times out because it can't access RDS (makes sense - I think - because CodeBuild isn't in the VPC, SG, etc). I can't seem to add the VPC due to it "Crossing stage boundaries". Saw your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72010255/650241 which seems to explain the issue with #2. Going to give #1 a shot I suppose, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @GiovanniS Glad to help.  #2 should be workable in your case.  CodeBuild can play nicely with a VPC, with some [extra config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html).   Similarly, the constraints in the referenced question don't seem to apply here.  Your post-step is simply consuming a CodePipeline Variable from an earlier action.  That being said, #1 is also a good, idiomatic solution if Lambda is an option for your migration task.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't solve it within a build step of a CDK Pipeline.

Rather I'd go for the `CustomResource` approach.
With Custom Resources, especially in CDK, you're always aware of the dependencies and when you need to run them.
This gets completely lost within a CDK Pipeline context and you need to find out/implement by yourself.

So, what does a Custom Resource look like?

```js
// this lambda function is an example definition, where you would run your actual migration commands
const migrationFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'MigrationFunction', {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.PROVIDED_AL2,
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('path/to/migration.ts'),
      layers: [
        // find the layers here: 
        // https://bref.sh/docs/runtimes/#lambda-layers-in-details
        // https://bref.sh/docs/runtimes/#layer-version-
        lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(this, 'BrefPHPLayer', 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:209497400698:layer:php-80:21')
      ],
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
      memorySize: 256,
    });

      const migrationFunctionProvider = new Provider(this, 'MigrationProvider', {
      onEventHandler: migrationFunction,
    });

    new CustomResource(this, 'MigrationCustomResource', {
      serviceToken: migrationFunctionProvider.serviceToken,
      properties: {
        date: new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString(),
      },
    });
  }

  // grant your migration lambda the policies to read secrets for your DB connection etc.
```

```js
// migration.ts
import child_process from 'child_process';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const sm = new AWS.SecretsManager();

export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  // an event provides more flexibility than env vars
  const { dbName, secretName } = event;

  // Retrieve the database credentials from AWS Secrets Manager
  const secret = await sm.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretName }).promise();
  const { username, password } = JSON.parse(secret.SecretString);

  // Run the migration command with the database credentials
  const command = `php artisan migrate --database=mysql --host=your-database-host --port=3306 --database=${dbName} --username=${username} --password=${password}`;
  child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  });
};
```

The `Custom-Resource` takes your migration lambda function.
The Lambda runs the actual command to do your database migration.
The Custom Resource is applied every time when running a deployment.
This is applied via the `date` value.
You can control the execution by altering any property within the `CustomResource`.

Comment: I do like this approach, and it seems the easiest, but the `artisan` command used to migrate the database (as well as the migration files) are Laravel (php) based. I could probably get something working with bref - https://bref.sh -  but maybe there is something i'm missing in this context?

Comment: Aah, sorry! Missed that information.
I don't have any PHP experience with AWS, but I checked some docs.
Bref is the way to go for using PHP as a runtime-environment in Lambda.
I'll edit my answer.